# Looping Forever

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to loop an exception, but for some reason its not giving me the option to re write my scanner file:

I don't know how to use BufferedReader so that's why I'm using this.  Any clues?

Here's my standard class with my method

```
package arrayExceptionsWithInput;
import java.util.*;
public class GetThoseNumbersBaby {

    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    boolean error;
    Scanner yourNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void findNumbers()
    {
        System.out.println(" please enter your first number");
        firstInt = yourNumbers.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" pleas enter your second number");
        secondInt = yourNumbers.nextInt();
        int finalInt = (firstInt+secondInt);
        System.out.println("total is: " + finalInt);
    }
}
```

And here's my main class with the exception being implemeted with a loop:

```
package arrayExceptionsWithInput;
import java.util.*;

public class InputException
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean error = false;
        GetThoseNumbersBaby zack = new  GetThoseNumbersBaby();


        {
            do {
                try
                {
                    zack.findNumbers();
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException Q)
                {
                    System.out.println(" one of your integers was incorrect, please try again");
                    Q.printStackTrace();
                    error = true;
                } 
            } while (error == true);
        }
        error = false;
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to loop this differently I'm all ears.

Comment: why have you wrapped the do-while inside {} ?

Comment: `while(error == true)`  ->   `while(error)`

Comment: while (error == true) would be more idiomatically written while(error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i decided too get rid of the method class
and just put the method into the try exception area.

used a .nextLine after scanner and it seems fixed.

this looks ok?

```
package arrayExceptionsWithInput;
import java.util.*;
public class InputException
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
boolean error = false;
int firstInt;
int secondInt;
Scanner yourNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);
{
    do{
            try
            {

                    System.out.println(" please enter your first number");
                    firstInt = yourNumbers.nextInt();
                    yourNumbers.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(" pleas enter your second number");
                    secondInt = yourNumbers.nextInt();
                    yourNumbers.nextLine();
                    int finalInt = (firstInt+secondInt);
                    System.out.println("total is: " + finalInt);
                    yourNumbers.nextLine();

            }
            catch(InputMismatchException Q)
            {

                Q.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(" one of your integers was incorrect, please try again");
                error = true;
                yourNumbers.nextLine();
            }   
        }while (error == true);
    }error = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Scanner keeps the answer and doesnt rests unless i put in yourNumnbers.NextLine()

Comment: It's more usefull if you edit your question with updates instead of adding updates by way of answers.

Comment: You still need to set error = false inside the loop, otherwise if you do hit an exception, error will be set to true and never cleared.

Comment: wait,  i see my mistake and what you mean but why when i set it too false inside the loop, then i realisd im setting it inside and just after the loop too the same thing. 

sorry for not updating, but if i wrote the answer in my original question, it wouldnt be a question. and would get closed by power hungry mods.

Answer (score 1):

Set error false *before* the action.  That way you have the correct exit condition if the user gets it right.

```
error = false;
zack.findNumbers();
```

Comment: sorry, still getting used too stacks interface. i didnt know i had enough rep to vote on posts

Answer (score 0):

You loop while *'error'* variable has value *'true'*. However, it becomes *'true'* only when the is thrown (i.e. when *'catch'* block is executed). Control flow doesn't reach it.